# connection count of 0 does not meet required minimum of 1

Tags: connection, runtime-error, simulation, system-verilog, uvm

I have a UVM/system-verilog environment that has 3 agents that are connected by analysis ports to the scoreboard. I am using questa on windows for simulation.
I get the error message:

***# UVM_ERROR @ 0: uvm_test_top.tx_machine_env.tx_machine_sb.Q_I_in_export [Connection Error] connection count of 0 does not meet required minimum of 1***

my monitor:

```
class qvsat_ib_tx_machine_desc_monitor extends uvm_monitor;

   `uvm_component_utils(qvsat_ib_tx_machine_desc_monitor)

    uvm_analysis_port#(qvsat_ib_tx_machine_desc_item) qvsat_ib_tx_machine_desc_ap;

    virtual qvsat_ib_tx_machine_desc_if tx_machine_desc_if; 
   //Constructor
   function new(string name = "qvsat_ib_tx_machine_desc_monitor", uvm_component parent);
      super.new(name, parent);
  endfunction

   function void build_phase(uvm_phase phase);
      super.build_phase(phase);
      qvsat_ib_tx_machine_desc_ap = new(.name("qvsat_ib_tx_machine_desc_ap"), .parent(this));
    endfunction: build_phase


   task run_phase(uvm_phase phase);
.
.
.
   endtask   

endclass
```

my agent:

```
class qvsat_ib_tx_machine_desc_agent extends uvm_agent ;
   `uvm_component_utils(qvsat_ib_tx_machine_desc_agent)

    uvm_analysis_port#(qvsat_ib_tx_machine_desc_item) tx_machine_desc_ap;

    qvsat_ib_tx_machine_desc_sequencer    tx_machine_seqr;
    qvsat_ib_tx_machine_desc_driver       tx_machine_driver;
    qvsat_ib_tx_machine_desc_monitor      tx_machine_monitor;

    qvsat_ib_tx_machine_desc_agent_config cfg;

   //Constructor
   function new(string name = "qvsat_ib_tx_machine_desc_agent", uvm_component parent);
     super.new(name, parent);
   endfunction

   function void build_phase(uvm_phase phase);

      uvm_report_info(get_full_name(),"START of build ",UVM_LOW);


      super.build_phase(phase);
      if ( ! uvm_config_db#( qvsat_ib_tx_machine_desc_agent_config )::get
            ( .cntxt( this ), .inst_name( "" ), .field_name( "desc_cfg" ), .value( cfg ) ) ) begin
         `uvm_error( "qvsat_ib_tx_machine_desc_agent", "cfg not found" )
      end
      tx_machine_desc_ap = new(.name("tx_machine_desc_ap"), .parent(this));
. 
.
.
      tx_machine_monitor          = qvsat_ib_tx_machine_desc_monitor::type_id::create(.name("tx_machine_monitor"), .parent(this));

      uvm_report_info(get_full_name(),"END of build ",UVM_LOW);

   endfunction: build_phase

   function void connect_phase(uvm_phase phase);
      uvm_report_info(get_full_name(),"START of connect ",UVM_LOW);
      super.connect_phase(phase);
.
.
.
      uvm_report_info(get_full_name(),"connecting analysis ports",UVM_HIGH);
      tx_machine_monitor.qvsat_ib_tx_machine_desc_ap.connect(tx_machine_desc_ap);
      uvm_report_info(get_full_name(),"END of connect ",UVM_LOW);
   endfunction: connect_phase

endclass
```

my envir:

```
class qvsat_ib_tx_machine_env extends uvm_env;
   `uvm_component_utils(qvsat_ib_tx_machine_env)


   qvsat_ib_tx_machine_desc_agent         tx_machine_desc_agent      ;
   qvsat_ib_tx_machine_sb                 tx_machine_sb;

   qvsat_ib_tx_machine_env_config         env_cfg      ;

   function new(string name, uvm_component parent);
      super.new(name, parent);
   endfunction: new

   function void build_phase(uvm_phase phase);
      uvm_report_info(get_full_name(),"START of build ",UVM_LOW);
      super.build_phase(phase);

      tx_machine_desc_agent        = qvsat_ib_tx_machine_desc_agent::type_id::create(.name("tx_machine_desc_agent"), .parent(this));

      uvm_report_info(get_full_name(),"END of build ",UVM_LOW);
    endfunction: build_phase

   function void connect_phase(uvm_phase phase);
      uvm_report_info(get_full_name(),"START of connect ",UVM_LOW);
      super.connect_phase(phase);
      if(env_cfg.scoreboard_en == 1'b1) begin
         tx_machine_desc_agent.tx_machine_desc_ap.connect(tx_machine_sb.desc_export);
      end
      uvm_report_info(get_full_name(),"END of connect ",UVM_LOW);
   endfunction: connect_phase
endclass: qvsat_ib_tx_machine_env
```

my scoreboard:

```
`uvm_analysis_imp_decl(_desc      )

class qvsat_ib_tx_machine_sb extends uvm_scoreboard;
    `uvm_component_utils(qvsat_ib_tx_machine_sb)

    uvm_analysis_export #(qvsat_ib_tx_machine_desc_item) desc_export      ;

    qvsat_ib_tx_machine_desc_item                        cur_desc;


    function new(string name, uvm_component parent);
        super.new(name, parent);

        uw_cnt            = 0;
        uw_simbole_cnt    = 0;
        data_cnt          = 0;
        pilot_simbole_cnt = 0;

        state          = IDLE;

    endfunction : new

    function void build_phase(uvm_phase phase);
       super.build_phase(phase);
        desc_export       = new("desc_export", this);
   endfunction: build_phase

    virtual function void write_desc(input qvsat_ib_tx_machine_desc_item  desc);
        cur_desc = desc;
        cur_desc.print();
    endfunction : write_desc
.
.
.


endclass
```

Note: I have 2 more agents that are connected to the scoreboard by another 2 different analysis ports, and I get the same error message for all of them.

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

I did the following change that solved that problem:
instead of

```
    uvm_analysis_export #(qvsat_ib_tx_machine_desc_item) desc_export      ;
```

I used:

```
    uvm_analysis_imp_desc       #(qvsat_ib_tx_machine_desc_item,qvsat_ib_tx_machine_sb) desc_export      ;
```

i.e
uvm_analysis_imp< `uvm_analysis_imp_decl name >

regards,
Ilan